# How to set the value of a variable defined outside in an arrow function (Axios, react, javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, variables, axios

I created a [React](https://reactjs.org) component which fetches data from a server using `Axios` and renders it in a `<p>` element.
Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

class Abc extends React.Component {
    getUser = () => {
        let r;
        Axios.get("...").then(res => {
            r = res.data();
        });
        return r
    }

    render() {
        return <p>User: {getUser()}</p>
    }
}
```

But the above code returns `user` as `undefined`. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** For those of you asking me to use `componentDidMount()` and `state`, I need to use this `user` variable multiple times, and all times, the `user` will be different. What do I do now?

**UPDATE:** Fixed it. I just created a separate component for every user. Thanks all!

Comment: what is `user`?

Comment: return inside then block

Comment: Send API call in `componentDidMount()` set the state and access only state variables inside render()

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi i didn't get you. User is an object i get from my api wentjun

Comment: Is there no other option @Vaibhav

Comment: `render()` will not wait for async operations it will show `undefined` or throw error

Answer (score 2):

You need use state, because getUser async method

```
class Abc extends React.Component {
    state = {
        user: null,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get("...").then(res => {
            this.setState({ user: res.data() });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { user } = this.state;

        if (!user) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>;
        }

        return <p>User: {user}</p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, looks like state is the only choice I have. I'll use it. Thanks everyone

Comment: I now have a new problem. I have to use user multiple times, and all times there are different users, what do i do now?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you can reuse `Abc` component and pass prop id like `<Abc id={123} />`, in `componentDidMount` you can use this id to request

Answer (score 1):

React can't render asynchronously component.
In your component, axios is used to fetch data from server.
This is performed asynchronously.
So you mustn't render your component asynchronously.
Solution is here:

1. Make a variable in your redux for user data.
2. Then do axios in your redux(action)
3. Finally, connect your redux store to your component and use it.